# Is it possible to have an active url in a tooltip in Google Map in Android

Tags: android

I want my tooltip to include a an active url link. Would it be possible in a MapView? Or do i have to place my MapView inside a WebView for this purpose? Any tutorial on the web? Any solution?

Here is something i require:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the tooltip overlay is combo View widget that you customized to include a textview I do not see why not..mark it as links clickable, see textview api for details..

Comment: Can you give me an example please?